# Get PID of a timed process, along with the output of time

Tags: bash, scripting, pid

I have this line of code:

```
{ time cp $PWD/my_file $PWD/new_file ; } 2> my_log.log
```

I need to know how long it takes to execute the 'cp' command and I also need to get the PID of the 'cp'. I just want to print the PID of the 'cp' process and get the following in the `my_log.log` file:

```
<output of time>
```

I have tried `PID=$!` but this does not provide PID of the `cp` process.

Comment: You want to know PID of cp or the PID of the process running in the background? Are you copying loads of files?

Comment: This is not really clear.... you want only the pid of the `cp` process in the log file? Do you want the output of time to the stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First, you need to send your (timed) `cp` command to the background with a trailing `&`, so you can inspect the running processes after launching it.
  (I suspect you're already doing this, but it's not currently reflected in the question).
- `$!`, the special variable that contains the PID of the most recently launched background job, in this case reflects the *subshell* that runs the `time` command, so we know that it is the *parent* process of the `cp` command. To get the (one and only, in this case) child process:

  - If your platform has the nonstandard `pgrep` utility (comes with many Linux distros and BSD/macOS platforms), use:
    `pgrep -P $!`
  - Otherwise, use the following POSIX-compliant approach:
    `ps -o pid=,ppid= | awk -v ppid=$! '$2 == ppid { print $1 }'`

To put it all together, using `prgep` for convenience:

```
# Send the timed `cp` command to the background with a trailing `&`
{ time cp "$PWD/my_file" "$PWD/new_file"; } 2> my_log.log &

# Get the `cp` comand's PID via its parent PID, $!
cpPid=$(pgrep -P $!)
```

Answer (score 2):

To know approximately how long takes cp command you can check new file size

```
size=$(stat -c %s "${old_file}")
cp "${old_file}" "${new_file}" &
cp_pid=$!
while kill -0 ${cp_pid}; do
    cpsize=$(stat -c %s "${new_file}")
    echo elapsed time $(ps -p${cp_pid} -oetime=)
    echo $((100*cpsize/size)) % done so far..
    sleep 3
done
```

EDIT: following comment `stat -c %s "${file}"` can be replaced by `du "${file}"` it's POSIX and more suitable command (see man page).

Comment: Nicely done. It's worth mentioning that `stat` is not a POSIX utility and that on BSD/macOS you'd have to use `stat -f %z` instead.

Comment: Why don't you use `du ${old_file}` instead of `stat`? `du` should be a POSIX utility.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia, thank you for your remark I didn't think about it,  moreover it's more suitable

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia: Yes, it's an answer to a different question, but shows a useful technique nonetheless. Small caveat re `du`: it reports the number of _blocks_ occupied on disk, which is not the same as the actual file size (even if you multiply with the block size to get a _byte_ count; POSIX doesn't support getting a _byte_ count at all, and only the _GNU_ `du` implementation supports `-b` for reporting the actual size, in bytes).

Comment: @mklement0: I completely agree with you... it is a really nice example! (I voted it ;). It is also interesting that there is no way to get the dimension of a file in byte in POSIX... Thank you for this infos.

Comment: there is also `wc -c`, but may be more expensive for big files

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one I can think of is

```
pgrep cp
```

Comment: `( time cp  $PWD/my_file $PWD/new_file & 2>&1; echo $! ) > my_log.log 2>&1`
Contents of my_log.log will be PID of the cp command followed by the timing output of the cp command.

Comment: OK -- will post answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK -- from the comments: "Contents of my_log.log will be PID of the cp command followed by the timing output of the cp command":

```
( time cp $PWD/my_file $PWD/new_file & 2>&1; echo $! ) > my_log.log 2>&1
```

First, you need to use `/usr/bin/time` explicitly, and pass the options to append to an output file.  Then, use `pgrep` on the name of the file you are copying (`cp` will get too many hits):

```
/usr/bin/time --output=my_log.log --append cp $PWD/my_file $PWD/new_file &  pgrep -f my_file > my_log.log
```

You may want to change the output format, because it's kinda ugly:

```
18400
0.00user 0.30system 0:02.43elapsed 12%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2520maxresident)k
0inputs+496424outputs (0major+141minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Answer (score 0):

Following what written in one of your comment above... the following is a proper answer:

The following code (just an example):

```
time (sleep 10 & echo -n "$!"; wait)
```

will return something like:

```
30406
real    0m10.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.005s
```

In your case:

```
time (cp $PWD/old_file $PWD/new_file & echo -n "$!"; wait) &>  my_log.log
```

will do the job.

I find this solution quite elegant since it's a "one liner" despite the "completely negligible overhead" you got in the timing (the timing will be related to the entire subshell (also the `echo` and the `wait`). That the overhead is negligible is evident from the result of the sleep command.

The `&>` redirect stdout and stderr to the same file (so you do not need to specify the `1>&2`).

Pay attention that doing

```
(time sleep 10 & echo -n "$!")
```

You will get the pid of the `time` process not `sleep` or `cp` in your case.